# Is there an option to log full stacktrace in an Azure web app?

Tags: azure-application-insights

I have an Azure web app hosted. I have turned on Application Insights but it doesnt give full details any exceptions or errors.
Is there an option in Application Insights i can use to log the full stack trace , so i can debug where in the code any error may have occurred ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Application Insights can handle all types of Application telemetry.

#### Application Insights Monitors below telemetry data

- **Dependency rates**, **Request/response times**, and **Failure rates** of your applications.
- **Exceptions** Analyze the aggregated statistics, or pick specific instances and drill into the **stack trace** and related requests. Application Insights reports both server and browser exceptions.
- **Pageviews** and **load performance** reported by users' browsers
- **AJAX** calls from web pages, including rates, response times, and failure rates
- **User** and **session** counts
- **Performance** counters such as **CPU, memory, and network** usage
- **Host diagnostics** from Docker or Azure
- **Diagnostic trace logs** from apps, correlate trace events with requests
- **Custom events** and **metrics** in client or server code that track business events.

Where to see [Application insights data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-insights-overview#where-to-see-application-insights-data)

Azure portal -> **Application Insights** -> **Investigate Section** (Failures, Transaction Search, etc.)/**Monitoring Section** (Logs Analytics, Alert, Metrics, etc.)

[image]

You can see the full stack trace in **End-to-End Transaction Details**.

[image]

Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-exceptions) for more information